# Django global variable disadvantages

Tags: python, django, django-views

What disadvantages are there when using django and defining variables like this then using them in the views???

```
logged_user = Logged_User.objects.all()


def logged_user(request):
    a = B.objects.filter(a = request.user)
    return render(request, 'a.html',{'a':a,**'logged_user':logged_user**})
```

Rather than

```
def logged_user(request):
    a = B.objects.filter(a = request.user)
    logged_user = Logged_User.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'a.html',{'a':a,**'logged_user':logged_user**})
```

With the first step, the logged_user is callable from any other view without having to rewrite everything.

Comment: Is `Logged_User.objects.all()` expected to return the same value every time you call it?

Comment: The two most obvious: 1. The value will be evaluated once and will not update and 2. In a production setup with threads and processes there will be multiple versions of "global" variables.

Comment: @khelwood, I think so, depending on the logged in user

Comment: Unless you know it's going to return the same value every time, calling it once (multiple processes notwithstanding) and reusing the value will give you different results from calling it each time you need it. The same reason you don't write the time down on a piece of paper and look at it every time you want to know the time.